# Main process exiting when subprocess exits - Python

Tags: python

Hope your day is well.
I am trying to execute a Python program from within a Python program (Making an API for my website backend), but when that program calls `exit()`, the main program exits as well,

```py
o = threading.Thread
(
    target=waitpid,                                                
    args=(["python3 test.py"], 'Extract', int(sys.argv[11])/2)
)
o.daemon = True
o.start()
o.join()
```

waitpid is:

```py
def waitpid(command, job, hours):
    print(command)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
    pid = proc.pid
    r.hset(sys.argv[7], "pid", str(pid))
    r.hset(sys.argv[7], "id", str(id))
    r.hset(sys.argv[7], "job", job)
    wait_to_kill(proc, int(hours), True, sys.argv[7])
```

`r` is a Redis connection,
`wait_to_kill` is:

```py
def wait_to_kill(proc, hours, iscached=False, id=None):
    time.sleep(hours * 3600)
    proc.kill()

    if iscached == True and id != None:
        r.delete(id)
```

And finally, test.py is:

```py
exit()
```

I feel like I am doing something horribly wrong, and I do not know why the main program exits when the subprocess finishes.

If you are wondering what I am trying to do, I am trying to create a new thread which will run a Python program, and then kill it after X amount of hours has passed.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: As i can see, your main program waits for child to complete on `o.join()`, and then the main program code ends, so it exits

Comment: This is the issue. Thank you. Although I need more help, how do I wait for threads to finish, and when they do finish my program continues executing instead of it being stopped by thread exiting